# Best freelance site to use as a writer?

Tags: freelance-websites

So, I've worked as a freelance copywriter for almost a year for different agencies, corporations and  friends/family.

I am having health issues and bad luck, so I am considering doing some freelance work to quit bouncing around for a while.

Unlike most people on these sites, I am American and have experience with national brands. I feel this gives me an edge.

Any site recommendations? I have never done this before and know my rate will be higher than a lot of people on these sites. At a regular non-remote job, I ask for 18/hr. Is this too high freelance-wise?

Comment: If you are a web developer (or know things about web), you can write at lots of sites like SitePoint, SmashingMagazine, TutsPlus etc. They pay well